# Powering Arduino Mega 2560 from a Raspberry Pi Usb

Tags: arduino-mega, nrf24l01+, raspberrypi

I have a Raspberry Pi B+ running 7x24. I have to connect an Arduino Mega 2560 to its USB. The Arduino has only one nRF24L01-PA-LNA powered from its 3V3.
Can I power the Arduino from the Pi's USB?

Comment: I think the quickest away of getting an answer would be to RTM.  Search for the technical specs and what ampage the Pi can put out and see what the mega draws.  TBH I suspect that it isn't going to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are powering your RPi from power supply 5V/2A at least there should be no problem. USB hub on the RPi should not give more than 500mA to power Arduino. Also there is a fuse on Arduino's board to prevent any damage from USB power.

Check both Arduino and RPi schematics for more details about modules used there:

- [Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-mega2560_R3-sch.pdf)
- [Raspberry](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/rpi3/raspberry-pi-3-b-reduced-schematics.pdf)

Comment: The power of the Pi looks OK. But! The 3V3 ouput of the Mega has 50mA output. The nrf24L01-PA-LNA consumes 45mA in receiver mode but needs 115mA in emission mode. Emission is a peak. Using capacitor would be a solution but it is on the limit, I think it's not the solution for 7x24.

Answer (score 1):

raspberry pi can power ur mega board normally,but the 3v3 in the mega board is not stable and has noise,so it is better to use 3v3 supply source for ur NRF the simplest to use is just hooking a piece of 1117 to 5v of ur mega board

Comment: Thanks, I got 5V from an other USB for the 1117 and for a capacitor. Works like a charm. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, as the others have mentioned you can power the Arduino form the raspberry pi's power supply, but you cannot transit data from the raspberry to the Arduino without a third party software.